# PHP Password Hashing in 2011

Tags: security, hash, passwords, salt

I'm bringing this up after spending a few hours trawling through a number of posts on SO with regards to the most secure way to handle passwords in PHP/MySQL. Most answers seem to be fairly out of date, as are links that people are directed to. Many recommend md5 and sha-1.

We all know that MD5 and SHA-1 are no longer worth using due to the fact that they have been reversed, and also because there are a number of databases out there that have built up millions of md5/sha1 strings. Now, obviously you get around this with salt, which I intend to do.

I have however recently started playing around with whirlpool, which seems much more secure, and up to date. Would I be right in thinking whirlpool+salt is ample protection for passwords?

I was actually considering something like this:

```
<?php
    $static_salt = 'some_static_salt_string_hard_coded';
    $password = 'some_password_here';
    $salt = 'unique_salt_generated_here';

    $encoded = hash('whirlpool', $static_salt.$password.$salt);
?>
```

What do you think? Overkill or sensible?

Comment: Hash algorithms cannot be reversed. You can only test against them.

Comment: Also see Openwall's [PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its portable and hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords. The guy who wrote the framework (SolarDesigner) is the same guy who wrote [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) and sits as a judge in the [Password Hashing Competition](http://password-hashing.net/). So he knows a thing or two about attacks on passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be enough (however, there is no sense in static hardcoded salt). And, why not to use SHA256? Whirlpool is rarely used.

Comment: My main thought for using whirlpool is that its a bit of an underdog. On the plus side, because its not used too much it's less likely to have publicly known vulnerabilities. On the downside, it may present future support and/or security problems.

Comment: The less used/tested cipher/hash, the more chances that it has hidden vulnerabilities :) All widely-used hashes are tested by the whole world's community, so there is much more chances that there will be no major vulnerabilities found.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably good enough for most applications.

However, salts become (almost) useless if your DB is leaked -- including the static one if your configuration file is leaked too. They are a good protection against rainbow tables, but nowadays it's easier to use a bunch of GPUs to brute-force a given hash.

IMHO, currently [the best solution is to use bcrypt](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/). It's apparently supported in PHP 5.3+, and [here's an example](https://gist.github.com/972386) of how to use it.

Comment: Correct answer. If you have to ask, the answer is 'use bcrypt'.

Answer (score 0):

It's particularly meaningless to discuss the merits of particular algorithms without a much wider consideration of the threat models and specifics of implementations.

Yes, whirlpool does appear to have some advantages in terms of how effective it is as a hash, but as Nickolay says that may be deceptive and due to the fact it is less widely used. But there are other considerations too - for some purposes storing a 128 character string for each account may be an unnecessary overhead. For everyone it's a question of what the software supports (and some people might want to use the same account record to control access to different systems).

At the end of the day, it doesn't matter how sophisticated your hashing algorithm is:

1. given a free choice, users pick bad, guessable passwords
2. users will use the same password for different services

If it works for you - then great - but there is no universal solution.